# What children's sci-fi novel has a girl on a space station who ends up on an alien planet?

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens, young-adult, space

I'm trying to remember the name of a novel for children or young adults that I read 12–14 years ago.

There is a girl who lives on a space station. I think the space station blows up or is compromised in some way. The girl is separated from her parents and ends up on a planet. She encounters aliens on this planet but can't interact because she is in a space suit.

Comment: This is a novel. It would have been 12-14 years ago that I read it.

Comment: I can't find the title, but it reminds me of a book I read probably about 5-6 years ago. In the book I'm thinking of, a girl becomes stranded on an alien planet after the escape pod she is hiding in is ejected due to an equipment malfunction. The aliens on the planet had highly dimorphic sexes with females generally being considered "superior" to males. The civilization was fairly primitive and believed in elaborate mythology that revolved around the trees on the planet; I think they believed the world grew from a fruit or something. Does any of this ring a bell?

Comment: That actually does. If you remember the title, you should post it.

Comment: @superchipmunk I'm having trouble finding the title, but if I do I'll get back to you.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds a little familiar to [The Dancing Meteorite](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/5040616-the-dancing-meteorite).

It’s about a young orphaned girl living on a space station. She has a natural affinity for linguistics and spends a large portion of her time studying alien languages. An event happens to the station (struck by the namesake meteorite if I remember correctly), and she then spends time on alien worlds (in a space suit) and on alien space stations with the crew of a spaceship assisting them with her linguistic skills.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on how this book matches the OP's description?

Answer (score 3):

Star Hatchling by: Margaret Bechard

Pretty sure this is the right one, I read this book a while back, but I couldn't remember the name... However, I remembered the image of the cover and googled until I found it.
http://books.google.com/books/about/Star_Hatchling.html?id=XmgbAQAAMAAJ

Comment: Please add some information about why you think this is the answer (e.g. details from the book that match the question's details).

Answer (score 3):

This story is similar in some ways to *Close to Critical* by Hal Clement, in which the young girl (with an alien friend) find herself stranded on a high-pressure planet aboard a bathyscaphe, and has to resort to asking for the natives' help.

> Unfortunately for Raeder's plan Aminadorneldo and Easy Rich, the
>   twelve-year-old daughter of Councilor Rich, have gone to tour the
>   bathyscaphe. While the two are alone aboard the craft, the bathyscaphe
>   suffers an accident that sends it onto a trajectory that will compel
>   it to land on Tenebra. Worse, although Aminadorneldo looks like an
>   adult Drommian, he is actually four years old, with the development
>   level of a seven-year-old Terran boy.

The two experience the weird conditions on the planet, with its shifting landscape and strange meteorology. In the end,

> they manage to get the natives to refuel the bathyscaphe, and are rescued.